# What is the performance impact of writing C# code in views which can also be written in controller/ business?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have done so to avoid extra View Model mappings in Business class. 
Example:

```
public class PatientInfoBusiness
{
    public List<PatientInfo> GetPatientInfo()
    {
        IPatientInfoService proxy = new VRFactory().GetPatientInfoServiceProxy();
        var piData= proxy.GetPatientInfoSectionData();

        //var patientInfoVM= new List<patientInfoVM>();
        //piData.ForEach( a => patientInfoVM.Add(
        //                                                          new patientInfoVM
        //                                                          {
        //                                                              AcknowledgedUserName = a.AcknowledgedUserName,
        //                                                              Description = a.Description,
        //                                                              PriorityCode = a.PriorityCode,
        //                                                              Status = a.Status
        //                                                          }
        //                                        )
        //                );

        return piData;
    }
}
```

Shifted the commented code in the above Business to View, looping through and displaying in HTML. This way no need of patientInfoVM View Model. **But I am skipping the business layer altogether and binding the entity from service layer directly in view!**

Comment: This becomes difficult to maintain in the future, but I personally think this reduces the load, normally the data generated are placed in the viewbag for transportation and when reaching the view some kind of converting and casting are required (I see performance over head unless using strongly typed views),  I too need to know the answer

Comment: Views should never contain business logic, at all, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any hard metrics I can only offer my opinion, but in lieu of other, more analytics-driven responses, here it is.

I would say **yes**, putting your business logic in a separate layer will cause slightly more overhead and therefore worse performance. Then again I would also say that I could squeeze more performance if I wrote in raw machine code, but that would be crazy. So here are my reasons why the **slightly worse** performance is worth it:

- maintenance of data-access code mixed in throughout your views will become a nightmare - you will end up re-writing the same access boilerplate code many times over (as you can't reuse the query logic in other views)
- views are typically JIT-compiled (unless you switch that off), and often the intellisense doesn't fully catch up with what you are doing, so you can leak compile-time bugs through to runtime
- debugging through views sucks - it just does
- mixing of your presentation code and your business logic is generally a "bad idea" - mainly because the two concerns become far too intermingled
- you are using a `List<>` in your example, which is a lower-performance convenience structure: so it's OK for that, why not for MVC?
- how do you error-handle in your view? Are you catching exceptions and outputting different markup? How does that translate into display templates, partial views and other such things?

Anyway, that's all my opinion: just ask yourself *why* you are using this framework, and what that last drop of performance might cost you in other ways. But the decision is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, based on the above points and since probably my production data isn't going to be huge, I have decided to let the logic be in the business itself.

Comment: Not a bad approach - I always think "fit for purpose" with these things: if you are happy with the performance as it is, use the convenience of the tools available. When your app becomes big and the performance starts to suffer, re-evaluate then when you know *why* you are tweaking :).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the **Maintainability vs Performance** shouldn't be the question here. It's all about *time*. The less time you need to develop/read/modify your solution, the better. Therefore you need to split your solution in layers. If something changes in the data-layer, you shouldn't have to modify your gui-layer.
Pre-optimalizations should not be done. But there are a few tricks to write your code more efficient.

You might return an `IEnumerable<patientInfoVM>`. This will create the `patientInfoVM` lazy. **This will only create the item when iterated.**

```
public class PatientInfoBusiness
{
    public IEnumerable<PatientInfo> GetPatientInfo()
    {
        IPatientInfoService proxy = new VRFactory().GetPatientInfoServiceProxy();
        var piData= proxy.GetPatientInfoSectionData();

        return piData.Select(a => new patientInfoVM
        {
          AcknowledgedUserName = a.AcknowledgedUserName,
          Description = a.Description,
          PriorityCode = a.PriorityCode,
          Status = a.Status
        });
    }
}
```

---

If you iterate the result only ones, you can just use it like this:

```
foreach(var patientInfo in GetPatientInfo())
{
    // do something.
}
```

---

But if you need to use the results more than ones, you should persist the items:

```
var patientInfoList = GetPatientInfo().ToArray();

foreach(var patientInfo in patientInfoList)
{
    // do something.
}

foreach(var patientInfo in patientInfoList)
{
    // do something.
}
```

Comment: Quite true: as long as the OP understands what deferred execution and lazy loading may cost him in other ways (N+1 queries, for example).